# replace multiple words in a string with array in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

lets say im making a translate system, it replace all the words that is matched in the array key with the value of the matched array key lets say

```
translate =
  saya: "i",
  jalan: "walk",
  hutan: "forest",
  beli: "buy",
  ke: "to",
  apel: "apple",
};
```

`string = "SaYa JaLan ke hutan beli Apel" // case insensitive`

it should be

`string = "I walk to forest buy apple" // the translated string`

how can we do that in javascript? in a function so we can call it like

`translated = translate(string) // returns the translated string`

Comment: not a good idea to do this in JS, even worse idea to translate a sentence merely by replacing words. If you are otherwise looking to learn how to replace strings in JS, read about the built-in [`.replace()` method at MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)

Comment: do you have any other suggestion? and why is not a good idea translate a sentence merely by replacing words in javascript?

Comment: First off, what are you *really* trying to do? a translating service or you just want to translate a parts of your site, or what?

Comment: a simple a translating service, for my tribe language in my small village

Comment: translating sentences can get complicated because you need to translate more than words sometimes. You might run in a situation where the words alone won't be able to represent what the sentence actually says. You have to worry about linking verbs/words, conjuring verbs and things like that which would have no exact word translation or words that can translate to more than one meaning. Therefore I'd advise against doing it in JS and instead have a server side solution and use JS to send text to be processed and retrieve them back once it's done

Comment: I haven't read the full article, but maybe [this series of posts](http://sinati.com/tree/using-google-translator-toolkit-add-your-language-%E2%80%9Cgoogle-translate%E2%80%9D) can help you. It's about integrating African 3 languages to google translation tool. I believe it's a series of 4 posts in total.

Comment: @MilkyWayJoe thank you for the share, yes, but inst node.js serverside? you mean sync programming?

Comment: @user1489281 Google Translate is able to translate the sentence you posted above, as shown here: http://translate.google.com/#id/en/SaYa%20JaLan%20ke%20hutan%20beli%20Apel However, Google's translation does not appear to be entirely accurate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
function translate(txt) {
    var translate = {
        saya: "i",
        jalan: "walk",
        hutan: "forest",
        beli: "buy",
        ke: "to",
        apel: "apple"
    };

    for (var key in translate) {
        txt = txt.replace(new RegExp(key, "ig"), translate[key]);
    }
    return txt.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + txt.slice(1);  //Capitalize the first
}                                                          // letter.

var translated = translate("SaYa JaLan ke hutan beli Apel");
//"I walk to forest buy apple"
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/2ucEk/

Comment: what is `ig`? can u explain more?

Comment: @user1489281 - `ig` means `g:Replace every word that matches, i:case insesitive`

Comment: `i` means case insensitive (it won't matter if words are upper or lower case); `g` means global, so it will check the whole string and not just the first occurrence (which is the default behavior in js as opposed to C# or other languages)

Answer (score -1):

JS noobie myself but I think this should work. The words are different but the process is the same

```
    lexicon = new Object();
lexicon.merry = "god";
lexicon.christmas = "jul";
lexicon.and = "och";
lexicon.happy = "gott";
lexicon.new = "nytt";
lexicon.year = "ar";

function translate(){

    //use to show translation:
    //have a merry christmas and a fun new year!
    var myString = document.getElementById('input').value;

    myString = myString.replace(/merry/g, lexicon.merry);
    myString = myString.replace(/christmas/g, lexicon.christmas);
    myString = myString.replace(/and/g, lexicon.and);
    myString = myString.replace(/happy/g, lexicon.happy);
    myString = myString.replace(/new/g, lexicon.new);
    myString = myString.replace(/year/g, lexicon.year);

    document.write(myString);
}
```

Comment: `new Object()` is bad. Multiple separate `replace` is bad.

Comment: @Derek, I should use braces and define it explicitly? Also, I realize it was inefficient but didn't know how to do it in a for loop until I saw this so thanks for explaining

Comment: For more about looping through an object, see the [MDN docs `for...in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in). `;)`